# Taylor series derivative values

Tags: calculus, power-series

Suppose

$$f(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2^2 + x^3/3^2 + … + x^k/k^2 + \cdots $$

What is the value of $f(0)$? $1$

What is the value of $f'(0)$ ? $1$

What is the value of $f''(0)$ ? $1/2$

What is the value of $f'''(0)$ ? $1/3$

However my answer for $f'''(0)$ is wrong. I don't understand why

Comment: Why do you think $f(x)$ is a taylor series? Where is the $!$ factorial part of each term?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Power series are unique, so...

Comment: I was asked to consider how these relate to taylor series. Considering that relationship, the coefficient is the derivative. So why is 1/3 wrong for f'''[0]?

Comment: @ZacharySelk I am sorry but I don't get it can you please elaborate ^_^

Comment: Ok well f'''[0] == 2/3. Although I still don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{1}{3!}f'''(0)$$

Multiply both sides by $3!$.